# Commented out variable is throwing error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've included a return function from my React Native code that is throwing an error (ReferenceError: Can't find variable: marker). This is the minimum code that reproduces the error; the only place that the variable marker appears is in the commented out line.

My understanding was that (on a basic level) commented code is thrown out by the compiler, so I don't understand why in this case the code that is within comments is being read.

Similar question:
[Commented code is throwing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409253/commented-code-is-throwing-error) -- in SQL, you need to be careful of making sure not to have an extra '*/' to uncomment your code. This doesn't seem to be the error with my code, as it happens whether I have commented out a single line with "//" or multiple lines with "/*..*/"

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
   <Text style={{flex: 1}}> Hi! Welcome to the Sacred Spaces App. </Text>

    <MapView 
   style={styles2.map}
   initialRegion={{
   latitude: this.state.latitude,
   longitude: this.state.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
   longitudeDelta: 0.0421}} />
   //     description={marker.description} 

  </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To comment something in JSX you need to wrap it with `{/* ... */}`.

JSX is not javascript and does not have the `//` comment syntax.

```
<MapView 
   style={styles2.map}
   initialRegion={{
   latitude: this.state.latitude,
   longitude: this.state.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
   longitudeDelta: 0.0421}} />
   {/*     description={marker.description} */}
```